# Placing a number between letters of a character expression

Tags: r

I would like to place an object result between a character expression

```
A<-2+2 # object 
zlog #carácter expression I would like to insert the result of an object
```

So it becomes

```
z4log
```

Comment: Why not use `sprintf` for example?

Comment: There is a specific place you want to place `A` to?

Comment: Or `paste` as an alternative, depending on whether you want something printed to the console or stored in an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
A <- 2+2 # object 
B <- "zlog" #carácter expression I would like to insert the result of an object 
sub('(?<=.{1})', A, B, perl = TRUE)
```

Correction is made according to @Pascal comment.
`T` is replaced with `TRUE`

Comment: Using `TRUE` is safer than only using `T`.

Comment: Would suggest the same: sub("(?<=\\w)",A,"zlog",perl=TRUE). with TRUE instead of T as recommended by @Pascal, though I would like to know when it's not safe to use it in this context.

Comment: @DJJ `T = 'bad habit'; sub('(?<=.{1})', A, B, perl = T); Error in sub("(?<=.{1})", A, B, perl = T) : 
  invalid regular expression '(?<=.{1})', reason 'Invalid regexp'`

Comment: @Pascal it is strange. 
I have no error on my system:
`A <- 2+2 # object` `B <- "bad habit"` `sub('(?<=.{1})', A, B, perl = TRUE)` `[1] "b4ad habit"`

Comment: @Pascal Only now it is clear to me, what you wanted to show me. Thanks.